# Only Allow Connection to Certain BSSID

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ssid

There are two networks with the same SSID. I want to ensure I only connect to the access point and never connect to the other one.

How can I allow AND prevent connection to wireless
networks based on their BSSID(MAC Address), when
their SSID(default/custom name) are the same and
changing SSID is not an option?

For example-

Allow connect/reconnect to:

SSID - Linksys

BSSID - AA-AA-AA-AA-AA-AA

....

Prevent connection to:

SSID - Linksys

BSSID - BB-BB-BB-BB-BB-BB

Answer (score 0):

That depends pretty much on your system.

On linux, you could just block all traffic from the MAC address of the other hotspot.

A quick google search brought me [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/iptables-mac-address-filtering.html)